# At the end, how does Chihiro knows that the parents are not among the pigs?

Tags: spirited-away

This is similar with

[How could Chihiro tell which pigs were her parents?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/52691/how-could-chihiro-tell-which-pigs-were-her-parents)

However, I asked what's in the end. That question asked in general.

However, in the beginning, Chihiro knows that her parents turn into a pig. They still wear the same clothes.

Latter Haku points which one are her parents.

What about at the last moment?

Because the explanation in [How could Chihiro tell which pigs were her parents?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/52691/how-could-chihiro-tell-which-pigs-were-her-parents) is not logical. Father mother relationship is strong then what? How the hell that explains things. It may make sense for feel gooder empathy people. It doesn't make sense to me at all

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126520/discussion-on-question-by-user4951-at-the-end-how-does-chihiro-knows-that-the-p).

Comment: This is answered on Movies SE: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/71055/how-exactly-did-chihiro-guess-it-right-in-spirited-away